# Firebase Firestore not responding

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Greeting, in general the problem is this, I created a web application using React JS, like a database using Firesbase Firestore. Everything worked fine until it was time to update the security rules (they were temporary, well, and time was up). It demanded to immediately change the rules, otherwise the base will stop responding after the expiration of the term. At first, I just extended the temporary rules, but it only worked once, after that all such attempts were in vain. After reading the documentation on writing security rules and looking at a couple of tutorials, I decided to write simple rules `allow read: if true; allow write: if false;`. In the project, the user does not interact with the base in any way, the text simply comes from the base and everything is essentially, so these rules are more than enough. I also additionally checked these rules on the emulator and everything went well. I saved the rules, but the application did not rise, I tried other options, to the extent that I simply put `true` everywhere and made the base completely open, but to no avail. I have already tried everything and crawled everything, but I still could not find a solution.

[image]

My app code:

```js
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { useDocumentData } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore'
import { CircularProgress } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Context } from '../../../index'
import { Dialog, DialogTitle, DialogContent, DialogActions, makeStyles, Button, FormControl, FormLabel, RadioGroup, FormControlLabel, Radio } from '@material-ui/core'
import langSwitcher from '../../languageSwitcher'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    modalBlock: {
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        color: "#308446",
    }
})

export function TestModal(props) {

    const cls = useStyles()

    let result = 0
    const [count, setCount] = useState(1)
    const [qCount, setQCount] = useState(1)
    const [answerArray, setAnswerArray] = useState([])
    const [answer, setAnswer] = useState("");
    const { firestore } = useContext(Context)
    const [test, loading] = useDocumentData(
        firestore.doc(langSwitcher('testEng/test', 'testUa/test'))
    )

    if (loading) {
        return (
            <CircularProgress />
        )
    }

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setAnswer(e.target.value)
    }

    const handleClick = () => {
        if (answer === "") {
            alert("!")
        } else if (count === test.ra.length) {
            setAnswerArray([...answerArray, answer])
            setCount(count + 1)
        } else if (count < test.ra.length) {
            setAnswerArray([...answerArray, answer])
            setAnswer("")
            setQCount(qCount + 1)
            setCount(count + 1)
        } else {
            for (let i = 0; i < answerArray.length; i++) {
                if (answerArray[i] === test.ra[i]) {
                    ++result
                }
            }
            alert(langSwitcher("Your result: ", "Ваш результат ") + result + "/" + test.ra.length + 
            langSwitcher(result >= 0 && result <= 4 ? " You are Junior!" : result >= 4 && result <= 8 ? " You are Middle!" : " You are Master!", "Ваш результат "))
            result = 0
            setCount(1)
            setQCount(1)
            setAnswerArray([])
            setAnswer("")
            props.updateTestState(false)
        }
    }

    const handleClose = () => {
        result = 0
        setCount(1)
        setQCount(1)
        setAnswerArray([])
        setAnswer("")
        props.updateTestState(false)
    }

    return (
        <Dialog open={props.testState} onClose={() => props.updateTestState(false)} aria-labeledby="form-dialog-title">
            <DialogTitle className={cls.modalBlock} id="form-dialog-title">{langSwitcher("Test", "Тест")}</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent className={cls.modalBlock}>
                <FormControl component="fieldset">
                    <FormLabel component="legend">{test['q' + qCount]}</FormLabel>
                    <RadioGroup aria-label="test" name="test" value={answer} onChange={handleChange}>
                        <FormControlLabel value={test['a' + qCount][0]} control={<Radio />} label={test['a' + qCount][0]} />
                        <FormControlLabel value={test['a' + qCount][1]} control={<Radio />} label={test['a' + qCount][1]} />
                        <FormControlLabel value={test['a' + qCount][2]} control={<Radio />} label={test['a' + qCount][2]} />
                        <FormControlLabel value={test['a' + qCount][3]} control={<Radio />} label={test['a' + qCount][3]} />
                    </RadioGroup>
                </FormControl>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions className={cls.modalBlock}>
                <Button type="submit" onClick={handleClick} color="primary">{count > test.ra.length ? langSwitcher("Result", "Результат") : langSwitcher("Confirm", "Підтвердити")}</Button>
                <Button onClick={handleClose} color="secondary">{langSwitcher("Cancel", "Скасувати")}</Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
    )
}
```

Error screenshot:[image]

Comment: Can you please share your code and a screenshot of what error you are getting?

Comment: @Dharmaraj ready

Comment: If either `testEng/test` or `testUa/test` (as appropriate) don't actually exist, their data will be set as `undefined`.

Comment: @samthecodingman damn, you're right, this is my carelessness, I have a language indicator and it showed another language for which there is no base yet. I checked it before and everything was fine, but for some reason the language indicator changed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as a Community Wiki as it's based on the comments of @samthecodingman and @spectrum_10101.

The error is being generated by either `testEng/test` or `testUa/test` not actually existing, so their data will be set as undefined. So it's likely that the root cause of this issue is located somewhere else in your app.